# core_compile.yml

Tags: configuration, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to load models thanks to the core_compile.yml. His meaning is to reduce the cost of IO operation, by having common files loaded.

I wish to load some of my models into it. But it looks like, it work only for custom class, or class which extended already loaded classes.

Does anyone know how to load these models ? I tryied by adding all needed classes, but when you have to include the class propel, the autoload try to load every propel file, and miserably fail. And it seems, i can't resolve this, unless i wrote a special propel class.

I'm using symfony 1.4 and propel 1.6(symfony plugin). Has anyone succeed to do this ?

That's mostly educationnal, the application is fast enough, the client has already deployed another version to production, so i can't say to my manager and my client, let's install APC.

Comment: Well, I can't see the profit of putting some models class inside this file. And I do not think it will make a significant improvement..

Comment: That's mostly educationnal, and not really needed. It will have the same interest than the 30 symfony files already loaded. I have some models as widely used as sfAction for example. I don't know if i would have a significant impact still, but that's why i wish to investigate.

Comment: The only reliable information I found about this file, is from [this blog](http://www.librosweb.es/symfony_1_1_en/capitulo18/optimizing_your_code.html). I never heard people hacking this file for optimisation by the way :) Have you checked the task `php symfony project:optimize` ?

Comment: Yeah i heard about it, but hadn't tryied yet, i am going to do this in a few minutes. I have saw others sources about this file, but only officials one, and they were saying exactly the same things. The sf PropelPlugin hadn't been built in order to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryied to explore this a bit. And it is basically impossible ...  at a reasonnable cost. You can load some isolated all purposes, stand alone class. Otherwise you have to explicitely load ALL the class called, inherited, ect ....

And with propel it is impossible. Because the propel files can't require each other this way. So you have to modify it.

So it may be possible to get a significant gain, but at a tremendously high cost. On my test server symfony need 200 ms of php execution in dev mode to send a blank page. Easier to upgrade php or use APC.